# Rotating multiple images on upload

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, file-upload

Working on a script that allows to rotate images on upload. It works fine for one image, but not for multiple images. I tried different things (like giving the `rotation` class its own name like so `class="rotation-1"`,`class="rotation-2"`, etc.  but I still couldn't make it work. How would you make the input file, jQuery code and `$rotation = $_POST['rotation'];` work for multiple images?

Here's the php part:

```
$path_escape = '/';

$uploadPath = "{$datadir['adpics']}{$path_escape}"; 

$statusMsg = ''; 
$upload = 0; 

if(!empty($fileName = $thisfile['name'])){ 
    $fileName = $thisfile['name']; 
    $fileType = $thisfile['type']; 
    $fileTemp = $thisfile['tmp_name'];

    $filePath = $uploadPath.basename($fileName); 

    // Allow certain file formats 
    $allowTypes = array('image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif');

    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 

        $rotation = $_POST['rotation']; 

        if($rotation == -90 || $rotation == 270){ 
            $rotation = 90; 
        }elseif($rotation == -180 || $rotation == 180){ 
            $rotation = 180; 
        }elseif($rotation == -270 || $rotation == 90){ 
            $rotation = 270; 
        } 

        if(!empty($rotation)){ 
            switch($fileType){ 
                case 'image/png': 
                    $source = imagecreatefrompng($fileTemp); 
                    break; 
                case 'image/gif': 
                    $source = imagecreatefromgif($fileTemp); 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTemp); 
            } 
            $imageRotate = imagerotate($source, $rotation, 0); 

            switch($fileType){ 
                case 'image/png': 
                    $upload = imagepng($imageRotate, $filePath); 
                    break; 
                case 'image/gif': 
                    $upload = imagegif($imageRotate, $filePath); 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    $upload = imagejpeg($imageRotate, $filePath); 
            } 

        }elseif(move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $filePath)){ 
            $upload = 1; 
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = 'Image upload failed, please try again.'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG/JPEG/PNG/GIF files are allowed to upload.'; 
    } 
}else{ 
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.'; 
} 


// Display status 
if($upload == 1){ 
echo '<h4>Image has been uploaded successfully</h4>'; 
echo '<img src="'.$filePath.'" width="300" height="auto" />'; 
}else{ 
echo '<h4>'.$statusMsg.'</h4>'; 
}
```

And then the input file and jQuery:

```
<span id="rleft-<?php echo $i;?>">Counterclockwise</span>
<span id="rright-<?php echo $i;?>">Clockwise</span></span>

<input type="hidden" name="rotation" class="rotation" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rotation" class="rotation" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rotation" class="rotation" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rotation" class="rotation" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rotation" class="rotation" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rotation" class="rotation" value="0">


 <script>

$(function() {
        var rotation = 0;
        $("#rright-<?php echo $i;?>").click(function() {
            rotation = (rotation -90) % 360;
            $(".file-preview-frame").css({'transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)'});

            if(rotation != 0){
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }else{
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }
            $('.rotation').val(rotation);

        });

        $("#rleft-<?php echo $i;?>").click(function() {
            rotation = (rotation + 90) % 360;
            $(".file-preview-frame").css({'transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)'});

            if(rotation != 0){
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }else{
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }
            $('.rotation').val(rotation);

        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Let's see the HTML code as well. I'm seeing suspicious use of id selectors when you said you used classnames.

Comment: @NathanHawks I updated the code.

Comment: `name="rotation"` should be `name="rotation[]"` then you will get an array of files.

Comment: @Nick Yes, how do I fetch them in an array in the php code, namely here: `$rotation = $_POST['rotation'];`

Comment: They will be in `$_FILES['rotation']`

Comment: @Nick Should it be something like this? `$rotation = array($_FILES['rotation']); 
if(in_array($rotation)){ .......}` When I echo $rotation it says Array Array Array, etc. How do I get the image rotation degree (ie 90, etc.) from that array?

Comment: @Alex333 you seem to be trying to pass the file and the rotation value through the same field. You need to have separate `<input>` elements for the file and the rotation value.

Comment: @Nick I am sorry I updated my original post. It's a hidden input. The file inputs are separate. The rotation happens in the hidden inputs. I need to get the value from the `value=`

Comment: OK, so you still need to use `name=rotation[]` and in your code you need to use the index into images to figure out which hidden element to update, it's hard to be certain but probably `$('.rotation').eq(<?php echo $i; ?>).val(rotation);` will work

Comment: @Nick Still can't make it work. It keeps throwing Array Array Array, etc. For some reason I can't pass the values from `value=""` into `$rotation = $_POST['rotation'];`. The input part is not an issue anymore. Where my issue is is I can't pass values from `value=""` into `$rotation = $_POST['rotation'];`.  I tried to use an array() and foreach() but it still throws Array Array Array, etc. I wish someone would show me how to change `$rotation = $_POST['rotation'];` to receive multiple `value=""` from the inputs.

Comment: `$_POST['rotation']` will be an array of the rotation values. You need to match them up to the corresponding entry in `$_FILES[]` e.g. `foreach ($_FILES['...']['name'] as $key => $filename) { $rotation = $_POST['rotation'][$key]; ... }`